# How to acces pseudo element(s) when its sibling is hovered

Tags: html, css

I have this html code :

```html
<div class="content">
   <h2><a href="#">Hero</a></h2>
   <h2>Hero</h2>
    <div class ="tricky"></div>
 </div>
```

where content is a flex container;tricky is another flex container with pseudo elements before and after that i want to use for effects when a is hover.(meaning i got `.tricky::before{...}` and `.tricky::after{..}` )
`.tricky, .tricky::before, .tricky::after` all of them are square width `visibility: hidden`.

I want when a is hover to affect all tricky's visibility to visible or any other change(ex: color/width/height anything) or one at a time(ex: `.content a:hover ~.tricky:before{...}`)

I tried :

`content a:hover ~(or + ).tricky:before { ...}` ; `content a :hover ~(or +)*{...}` and no method works.

Any help?
Thank you.

---

So i have this:
I want when a is hover to affect tricky's pseudo elements like tricky::before{...} to be able to change his visibility,width,height and same for ::after.

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;



}



.content{
  position:relative;
  top:200px;
  left:300px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:transparent;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:20px;


}


.content::before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:250px;
  background:linear-gradient(cyan,purple);
  animation:4s borderef linear infinite;


}

.content::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background:linear-gradient(red,white);
  inset:3px;

}




/* hero a(linkul) sta in fata, iar h2 sta in spate*/
.content a{
  position:absolute;
  color:red;
  transform:translate(-50%,0);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px yellow;
  font-size:2.5rem;


  text-decoration:none;
  z-index:3;

}

.content h2:nth-child(2){

    color:blue;
    font-size:2.5rem;



    animation:animate 4s ease-in-out infinite;
    z-index:3;



}

.tricky{
  position:absolute;
  display:flex;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:20px;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;


}
.tricky::before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:30px;
  height:130px;
  background:radial-gradient(yellow,cyan);
  animation:4s borderef2 linear infinite;
  border-radius:20px;
  z-index:2;
  visibility:hidden;



}

.tricky::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background:linear-gradient(yellow,white);
  inset:5px;
  z-index:2;
  visibility:hidden;
}


#ida:hover ~ .tricky::after{
  content:"";
  background:black;
  visibility:visible;
}




@keyframes animate {
0% ,100%
{
  clip-path: polygon(0% 45% ,15% 44% ,32% 50%, 54% 60% ,70% 61% ,84% 59%, 100% 52%, 100% 100% ,0% 100%) ;

}

50% {
clip-path:  polygon(0% 60% ,16% 65% ,34% 66% ,51% 62% ,67% 50%, 84% 45% ,100% 46%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%) ;

}





}


@keyframes borderef{
  0% {
  transform:rotate(0deg) ;
}
100%{
  transform:rotate(360deg) ;
}

}



@keyframes borderef2{
  0% {
  transform:rotate(0deg) ;
}
100%{
  transform:rotate(-360deg) ;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>



    <div class="content">

      <h2><a id ="ida" href="#">Hero</a></h2>
      <h2>Hero</h2>

      <div class ="tricky">
        </div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will it be okay to use JavaScript?

Comment: i dont know yet JS,i prefer with html/css but if its impossible, then yes

Comment: Hi, did the answer help? If no please let me know, and if yes please mark it as an answer. :)

Comment: Please provide a working snippet which shows the sort of thing you are trying to do. Some things can be made to seem to work OK using CSS but some others not.

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are required to manage your questions' lifecycle. That means, that if you get answers, and they solve your problem, pick the answer that answers it best. If not, comment on the answers given and explain why these do not help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. Are you looking for this? The `::after` content will show whenever any previous sibling `h2` is hovered.

```css
h2:hover~.tricky::after {
  content: "123";
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h2><a href="#">Hero</a></h2>
  <h2>Hero</h2>

  <div class="tricky"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this? .tricky::after will show on h2's Hover

```css
h2:hover~.tricky::after {
  content: "123";
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h2><a href="#">Hero</a></h2>
  <h2>Hero</h2>

  <div class="tricky"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need both h2 because hero contains 'water'wave animation.I want when a is hover i can affect tricky`s states.

Comment: Here when only a is hover, can't do this with only css, because a is in h2 and does not work sibling selectors

Comment: I understand,thank you.

Comment: @GiorgiEnuqidze Please add your code as a snippet so people can run and try it. I did that for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `onmouseover` and `onmouseleave` event listener to track the hover and out event and added/removed the `visibleAfter` class which will take care of the styling of `content::after` in the `CSS`

```js
const link = document.getElementById('link');
const tricky = document.getElementById('tricky');

link.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=>{
  tricky.classList.add('visibleAfter')
})

link.addEventListener('mouseleave', ()=>{
  tricky.classList.remove('visibleAfter')
})
```

```css
.tricky, .tricky::before, .tricky::after {
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: #777;
  position:relative;
}

.tricky::before, .tricky::after{
  content: '';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.tricky::before{
  top:.5em;
  left:.5em;
  background:red;
}

.tricky::after{
  top: 1em;
  left:1em;
  background:green;
}

.visibleAfter::after {
  visibility: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
   <h2><a id='link' href="#">Hero</a></h2>
   <h2>Hero</h2>
    <div id='tricky' class="tricky"></div>
 </div>
```